# Why does separating my module into multiple files make it slower?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, python-3.5, cpython

I made a Python module ([`swood`](https://github.com/milkey-mouse/swood)) that, up until recently, was one large file with many classes. After refactoring related classes into separate files, everything still works, albeit around 50% slower. I assumed that, if anything, it would get a little faster because Python could more efficiently cache the bytecode for each file, improving the startup time.

I am running this code with CPython (haven't tested with PyPy and its ilk). I've run `line_profiler` on the old and refactored versions and the percentage of processing time spent on each line looks roughly the same before and after the refactor.

Here are some things about my program that might have something to do with it:

- It makes a lot of small classes like [`Note`](https://github.com/milkey-mouse/swood/blob/5139f6a7bf17cbda6a863ebdf247446c9b1a60ee/swood/midiparse.py#L8) and instantiating these might be expensive, though this wasn't a problem before the refactor.
- When making these classes it gets them from a separate file it `import`s at the beginning.
- There is a lot of `numpy`-based array manipulation happening in the part that takes longest ([scaling](https://github.com/milkey-mouse/swood/blob/5139f6a7bf17cbda6a863ebdf247446c9b1a60ee/swood/renderer.py#L33) and [mixing](https://github.com/milkey-mouse/swood/blob/5139f6a7bf17cbda6a863ebdf247446c9b1a60ee/swood/wavcache.py#L16) audio)
- I have a cache that I store the scaled notes in, if they are used more than three times in 7.5 seconds. ([code](https://github.com/milkey-mouse/swood/blob/5139f6a7bf17cbda6a863ebdf247446c9b1a60ee/swood/renderer.py#L96))

What is causing my code to get slower after doing nothing but separating it into multiple files?

Comment: You probably messed up at some point. Separating your code into more modules would cause it to take a little longer to load all the modules, but that slowdown would be much lower than what you report. Nothing jumped out at me as obviously slow at a glance, but I did see some weird things (like `__hash__` without `__eq__`) suggesting that your code probably isn't bug-free.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some more benchmarking it was one of the things I suspected: having to access the functions/classes from another module meant another lookup for the Python interpreter, and the slight slowdown added up in some tight loops. [The Python wiki has something about this, too:](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips?highlight=%28Avoiding%20dots...%29)

> **Avoiding dots...**
>
> Suppose you can't use map or a list comprehension? You may be stuck
>   with the for loop. The for loop example has another inefficiency. Both
>   newlist.append and word.upper are function references that are
>   reevaluated each time through the loop. The original loop can be
>   replaced with:
>
> ```
> upper = str.upper
> newlist = []
> append = newlist.append
> for word in oldlist:
>     append(upper(word))
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Your refactoring seems to have done a lot more than just move classes into different files. For instance, `UncachedWavFile` lost a `__setitem__` method. And, in other places magic numbers have been changed. I would suggest you look elsewhere for the slow down first.

I wouldn't expect to see any difference in speed from refactoring your code base into separate files, expect perhaps a small (tiny even) decrease in start up time. I would suggest branching before the split and literally only separating the code into separate files, profiling your code's performance and then slowly adding the code you have added since the split and profiling each time to see what's slowing down your code.